# IXmlSerializable and XmlAttribute - How can I make it work like DateTime does?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-attribute

I have a class that has a fairly simple string representation. Serializing and deserializing to and from this string is not difficult.

What I would like to be able to do is use an XmlAttribute like so:

```
public class MyClass
{

     [XmlAttribute("MyValue")]
     public MySubClass {get; set;}

}
```

So that `MySubClass`, whenever it's serialized, can appear as an attribute:

```
<Myclass MyValue="XXYYZZ">
// other stuff omitted
</MyClass>
```

I'm currently attempting to use IXmlSerializable in `MySubClass`, but I get this serialization exception:

> XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode types implementing
>   IXmlSerializable."

I know this is possible because it works with DateTime. I've looked at the source code for DateTime and I see that ISerializable is implemented, but thats for binary serialization. I also see IFormattable implemented, but I don't know if that's the trick.

**Question: how can I make a class that behaves just like DateTime when it comes to xml serialization within xml attributes?**

Comment: How do you get "XXYYZZ" from an instance of `MySubClass`?  Perhaps just overriding the `ToString` method on `MySubClass` will do it.

Comment: How I get the string depends on how I serialize it. If I use IXmlSerializable, then it's in the ReadXml and WriteXml functions. I do have a ToString function but serializing the class still generates the exception message "XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types."

Comment: I meant that when you want to serialize the `MySubClass` instance, do you always want the value of a particular property of that class or is it derived from several properties?  Perhaps you can make that property not serializable (using `XmlIgnore`) and then create another one where the getter returns the value that you want serialized.

Comment: Think of MySubClass as being like a string or an int or datetime - it's just a single value that can be represented as a string, and parsed back again.

Comment: I don't want to use the XmlIgnore trick because I want to use this in a bunch of places and I don't want duplicate properties everywhere. I just want a class that behaves like `DateTime`.

Comment: Unfortunately the magic is not inside the DateTime class, the XmlSerializer itself has special codepaths for DateTime.